# Display custom post taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

This should be fairly simple and Im not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to display the tags associated with my custom post.

I have registered it like so

```
// Initialize Taxonomy Labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Tag' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tag:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tags' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
    );

    // Register Custom Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('tagevents',array('events'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true, // define whether to use a system like tags or categories
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tag-events' ),
    ));
```

but I cannot display the tags associated with the single page.

I have tried (among other things) `<?php  the_tags('<span class="tags-button">Tags :  ',' ','</span><br />');  ?>` which I use in my posts single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_tags` is only for the `post_tag` taxonomy, use [`the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) to output custom taxonomies with a similar format:

```
the_terms(
    $post->ID,
    'tagevents',
    '<span class="tags-button">Tags : ',
    ' ',
    '</span><br />'
);
```